# How to get user details on FOSUserBundle logout page?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, logout

I am using `FOSUserBundle` in `Symfone 2.8` webapp project. Currently the user is simply redirected to the homepage when he logs out. This should be changed to a "personal" logout page that can (optionally) display personal information (e.g. reminders for upcoming tasks or simple "Goodbey USERNAME" instead of just "Goodbey")...

So I need to access/use details of the currently logged out user. But since the user has just been logged out, I cannot access the user object any more?

**How to solve this?**

This is the configuration I use:

```
// config
security:
    ...  
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        main:
            ...
            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: /logoutpage


 // route
 <route id="user_logout" path="/logoutpage" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Default:logout</default>
 </route> 


 // Controller action
 public function logoutAction() {
    $loggedOutUser = HOW_TO_GET_USER(???);

    $template = 'AppBundle:Default:logout.html.twig';
    return $this->render($template, array('user' => $loggedOutUser));
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way would be to save the User's name/data in the session within an **EventSubscriber/Listener** that listens for a `security.interactive_logout` event.

The 2 problems arising thereby would be:

- there is no logout event dispatched by the default `LogoutHandler`
- symfony clears the session on logout per default configuration

You can change the session-clearing behavior by setting `invalidate_session` to `false`

```
security:
  firewalls:
    main:
      # [..]
      logout:
         path: 'fos_user_security_logout'
         target: '/logoutpage'
         invalidate_session: false # <- do not clear the session
         handlers:
           - 'Namespace\Bridge\Symfony\Security\Handler\DispatchingLogoutHandler'
```

For the logout event you can create a logout handler like this:

```
class DispatchingLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandlerInterface
{
    /** @var EventDispatcherInterface */
    protected $eventDispatcher;

    /**
     * @param EventDispatcherInterface $event_dispatcher
     */
    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $event_dispatcher)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $event_dispatcher;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(
            SecurityExtraEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGOUT,
            new InteractiveLogoutEvent($request, $response, $token)
        );
    }
}
```

Add some service configuration (or use autowiring):

```
  Namespace\Bridge\Symfony\Security\Handler\DispatchingLogoutHandler:
    class: 'Namespace\Bridge\Symfony\Security\Handler\DispatchingLogoutHandler'
    arguments:
      - '@event_dispatcher'
```

Events class

```
namespace Namespace\Bridge\Symfony;

final class SecurityExtraEvents
{
    /**
     * @Event("\Namespace\Bridge\Symfony\Security\Event\Logout\InteractiveLogoutEvent")
     */
    const INTERACTIVE_LOGOUT = 'security.interactive_logout';
}
```

Event itself:

```
final class InteractiveLogoutEvent extends Event
{
    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var Response
     */
    protected $response;

    /**
     * @var TokenInterface
     */
    protected $token;

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Response $response
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * @return TokenInterface
     */
    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    /**
     * @return TokenInterface
     */
    public function getRequest()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return SecurityExtraEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGOUT;
    }
}
```

And the subscriber:

```
class UserEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    protected $logger;

    /** @param LoggerInterface $logger */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // inject the session here
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            SecurityExtraEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGOUT => 'onInteractiveLogout',
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onInteractiveLogout(InteractiveLogoutEvent $event)
    {

        $user = $event->getToken()->getUser();

        // save the username in the session here

        $this->logger->info(
            'A User has logged out.',
            array(
                'event' => SecurityExtraEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGOUT,
                'user'  => array(
                    'id'    => $user->getId(),
                    'email' => $user->getEmail(),
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Enable the subscriber by tagging it with `kernel.event_subscriber`

```
  Namespace\EventSubscriber\UserEventSubscriber:
    class: 'Namespace\EventSubscriber\UserEventSubscriber'
    arguments: ['@monolog.logger.user']
    tags:
      - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber' }
```

Easy huh? A somewhat dirty solution would be creating a request listener that saves the username in the session-flashbag on every request so you can get it from there in the logout-page template.